# Missing year / numTracks when searching using Spotify Apps API

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to do an album search using the Spotify Apps API, but there is missing data in the  results. Specifically, the numResults is always 0, and the year is sometimes 0. For example:

```
var search = new models.Search("genre:Jazz");
search.searchTracks = false;    
search.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function() {
    console.log(search.albums);
    for(var i in search.albums) {
        console.log(search.albums[i].data.year)
    }
});
search.appendNext();
```

If you look at the console, many albums return 0 for year. But if you check these albums using the Metadata API, they successfully return a year. Interestingly, if you search for tracks at the same time, you get better results:

```
var search = new models.Search("genre:Jazz");
search.searchTracks = true;
search.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function() {
    console.log(search.albums);
    for(var i in search.albums) {
        console.log(search.albums[i].data.year)
    }
});
search.appendNext();
```

However, year is still missing on some albums (presumably the albums that had no tracks returned in the 50 track search results).

Does anyone have ideas on how to structure the search query, so that the year is returned for all albums, or is it probably a bug?

(Note: once you run the second code sample for a genre, the first code sample returns better results due to caching. Try it on a new genre and you'll see lots of 0s for year).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're observing the `models.EVENT.CHANGE` event on the album you want - that information is loaded separately and often lazily.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help. it seems that the album results returned from search are not always properly formed. i'm having issues elsewhere trying to create a player object from a searched album. my guess is that there's a bug somewhere, or perhaps the way search is designed means that albums are sometimes missing info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using models.Album.fromURI on each album to ensure that metadata is loaded. Something like this:

```
var search = new models.Search("genre:Jazz");
search.searchTracks = false;    
search.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function() {
    console.log(search.albums);
    for(var i in search.albums) {
        var a = models.Album.fromURI(search.albums[i].uri, function(album) {
          console.log(album.year)
        }
    }
});
search.appendNext();
```

I've used this sort of thing in an app I have been working on, and it seems to help ensure that the data is complete.